# centos7 I set this script to boot, after reboot The service did not start up

Tags: linux, shell, centos, boot

Run the shell script with the boot already included

```bash
cd /source/finance-calendar
nohup npm run server:prod >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

It is possible to start the service normally.
But I set this script to boot, after reboot
The service did not start up, what caused this?

Comment: What is finance-calendar?

Comment: Write a [systemd service unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) for it and then enable it with `systemctl enable finance-calendar.service`. Then it will be started at each boot.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my question.
I add PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/softwate/node-v10.14.2-linux-x64/bin to .bash_profile, so it can run the shell script when i finish starting my system.
But it can't start before user login.
So, I link npm and node to /use/bin，it will start.